# Render one React component inside other

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, material-ui

I am new to react & I am using material-ui and I want to design a custom autocomplete in React where once data is selected from dropdown it appears as a chip in the text input. I am using the `onNewRequest` property of material-ui autocomplete but I am not sure how to render a chip component inside it. 
Can someone guide me how to do it properly? I want to design recipients like layout found in gmail. I know there are npm packages available but I need to design it purely from material-ui so please guide with a proper approach

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is too broad as currently put. To shorty answer the question in the title, I'd say "you don't, you instantiate another component in a component's render function". Consider doing further research in the [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/hello-world.html), then produce a [MCVE] of the problem once you stumble upon a concrete issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is very broad but I'll try to at least point you in the right direction.

You don't need to render the chips inside the autocomplete, create a a new reusable component. The parent component will contain both the autocomplete and the chips. This will contain all the state. It has two child components:

The first child is always going to be the autocomplete, modify the material-ui styles to make it transparent and without an underline/borders. Whenever an element is selected, send an event to the parent to add the element to the chips array in the parent state.

The second child is the array of chips. This is only a presentational component, receives an array of chips, and the chips might contain another prop event to remove the chip.

Comment: So it will be like hiding the chips and showing then on blur?

Comment: In the beginning the array will be empty so the second component will show nothing. When the user selects something from the autocomplete, add it to the array and it will appear in the chips component. Why do you need to hide the chips?

Comment: I don;t need to I just want to show them as a single component juts like Gmail Recipient.I fi do it like this they will show up on different lines so should I style them to show them as one like juts like Gmail?

Comment: yup, style them to display inline instead of block